# What does the $O(Y^2)$ term mean in the BCH formula? What does the total formula expand out to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, operator-theory

I'm looking at the article [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases) formula and I have a few questions.

Under the "Special cases" section, there is a notation $\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad}$

$$ \log(e^X e^Y) = X + \frac{\ad_X}{1 - e^{-\ad_X}}Y + O(Y^2),$$

but it doesn't provide a reference for this formula.

What does the $O(Y^2)$ term expand to? What is the total sum? What is $O(Y^3)$ and $O(Y^4)$? Is there a total formula?

Comment: $O(Y^2)$ means an unspecified sum of terms containing $Y^2$. That is, the LHS is a formal power series in $Y$ with coefficients in (formal power series in $X$), and the RHS provides the first two terms of this series in $Y$ only.

Comment: Are there any references for the explicit structures associated with $Y^2$ and $Y^3$ and so on?